# Submit REST Request and GET Response without reloading page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to display result of a rest request without reloading the page.
Am using RAVE
Here is the post url
https://ravesandboxapi.flutterwave.com/flwv3-pug/getpaidx/api/resolve_account

Here is the json

```
{
    "recipientaccount": "0690000034",
    "destbankcode": "044",
    "PBFPubKey": "FLWPUBK-4e9d4e37974a61157ce8ca4f43c84936-X"
}
```

Here is the response

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "message": "ACCOUNT RESOLVED",
    "data": {
        "data": {
            "responsecode": "00",
            "accountnumber": "0690000034",
            "accountname": "Ade Bond",
            "responsemessage": "Approved Or Completed Successfully",
            "phonenumber": null,
            "uniquereference": "FLWT00976651",
            "internalreference": null
        },
        "status": "success"
    }
}
```

Here is the html form

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="full_name">
    <input type="email" name="email">
    <input type="text" name="recipientaccount">
    <select name="bankcode">
        <option value="044">ACCESS BANK</option>
    </select>
    <!-- Display Account Name from the json response -->
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: in order to help show the js code you are using to submit the post request and get json response

Comment: i don't have any

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery Ajax. It's a way of making a HTTP request asynchronously in the background, so it doesn't need page refresh.
The syntax is:

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  let form = $(this).serialize();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://ravesandboxapi.flutterwave.com/flwv3-pug/getpaidx/api/resolve_account',
    method: 'POST',
    data: form,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){ 
      //success function
      //return data form server
      console.log(data)
    },
    error: function(data){ //error function
      console.log(data)
    }
  });

});
```

Reference:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @Oriname if it helps it would be much appreciated to mark my answer as selected :)

Comment: didn't work out, also i need the account name to display above the submit button before clicking submit

Comment: Open your network tab, and see does the request get executed. See what the response is. Also check your console. What does it say?

Comment: You don't even have the JS code in your page. And why are you working on a live server? Where is your development environment? That's just bad habit.

Comment: i just uploaded there for you to see, so what's the issue

Comment: You don't have the javascript code in the link you sent me. That's why it's not executing lol.